# How to apply single page code in squarespace?

Tags: css, styles, squarespace

I am trying to add vertical lines to separate blocks of text on a single page in squarespace. This is my code, but it is not working. (I took out the actual block ID numbers) Please help!

```
<style>
  @media only screen and (min-width:640px)
{
#block-2, #block-3 
  {border-left: 1px solid #fff}
#block-4, #block-5
  {border-right: 1px solid #fff}
}
</style>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are on the right screen size ? Please verify on the developper tool if the @media is applying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to provide your HTML code as well.
but there might the case that you are using #fff color which is white and hence you are not able to see it.

If it does not work then pls share the HTML code too wanted to see where you have put the selector.

Comment: Just had to fix the color. Thanks!